# Restrict creation of VMs on GCP projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking to **Restrict creation of VMs on GCP projects**. Any workaround for this request.

We have a scenario to restrict the VMs under few projects not all projects and it should not be override by any project owner or folder owner.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) if you do a proper role segmentation within the users of your organization you can restrict all users/groups from creating VMw on your GCP project.
Here is another link regarding [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview)

Comment: Does it also restrict creating GKE instances ?

Comment: Yes it does, you can grant or revoke permissions for each action you perform within GCP Console.

Comment: I am only looking to control stop Creating VM Instance  and Open GKE to use.